# Programmatically authenticate External Credentials Principal In Named Credentials

Tags: rest, salesforce, apex

[image]I have created an Auth Provider and Named Credential using Apex, with External Credentials. However, to authenticate it, I need to navigate to Setup manually> Named Credential > External Credential > Principal > Action and then Authenticate. Is there a way to automate this process in Apex, so that when I dynamically create the Named Credential, it will authenticate automatically and I can omit the manual step?